# How to simulate opening of .BAT file without one?

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, command-prompt

I want to launch several Perl scripts one after another (although, technically in parallel here) automatically.

It is easy to make a routine where the script makes a trivial .BAT file consisting only with the next Perl script, for example:

```
write_file("Z.bat", "$myfile_nextnumber.pl\n");
system "start Z.bat";
```

and you get nice output from each script in a separate window.

But how to achieve this without creating any file?

The closest what I got:

```
system "start cmd /k $myfile_nextnumber.pl";
```

but in this case, it does not show the path and file that was executed.

Comment: What about `start cmd /K title $myfile_nextnumber.pl & $myfile_nextnumber.pl`?

Comment: @aschipfl if you use the `&` operator you must enclose all commands for `cmd` in double quotation marks as mentioned in the [reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx), then you need to use single quotation marks to enclose all string starting from `start` but then you cannot pass variables in the string.

Comment: You can also escape the `&` like `^&`...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put a `print` statement before each system call?

```
foreach my $file (@filelist) {
  print "Calling $file\n";
  system "start cmd /k $file";
}
```

Comment: In my case, I want that the current Perl script calls the next one, but not like when there is one main script calling other scripts. That means I would need to add the `print` statement to the beginning of every Perl script.